# ReSharper Type Member Layout Namespace Members

Tags: resharper

I already understand how to re-order type members within a class. What I'm looking for is a way to reorganize the members within a namespace (in the same file) that exist outside a class. For example, given the code below:

```
namespace test
{
    public enum StandaloneEnum { //<enum values> }
    public struct StandaloneStruct { //<struct implementation> }
    public class StandaloneClass
    {
        public enum NestedEnum { //<enum values> }
        public struct NestedStruct { //<struct implementation> }
        class NestedClass { //<class implementation> }
    }
}
```

I can reorganize the nested members, but is there a way to re-order the standalone members, using ReSharper's type member layout feature? I understand that that it's *type* member layout, but I was hoping it abstracted out further than that, and I'm just missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, ReSharper's code cleanup will reorder type members, but not type declarations. If you wish to, you can suggest a feature at the [JetBrains YouTrack instance](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=RSRP&clearDraft=true&c=)

Comment: Well, to clarify, it **does** reformat type declarations that are within the scope of the class, but I get your drift.